# Ruby on Rails JWT ECDSA / ES256 usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

Estoy planeando usar jwt en mi aplicación rails con https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt y el algoritmo ES256, el ejemplo de uso en los docs es así

```
ecdsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new 'prime256v1'
ecdsa_key.generate_key
ecdsa_public = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new ecdsa_key
ecdsa_public.private_key = nil

token = JWT.encode payload, ecdsa_key, 'ES256'

# eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoidGVzdCJ9.AlLW--kaF7EX1NMX9WJRuIW8NeRJbn2BLXHns7Q5TZr7Hy3lF6MOpMlp7GoxBFRLISQ6KrD0CJOrR8aogEsPeg
puts token

decoded_token = JWT.decode token, ecdsa_public, true, { algorithm: 'ES256' }

# Array
# [
#    {"test"=>"data"}, # payload
#    {"alg"=>"ES256"} # header
# ]
puts decoded_token
```

Y quería preguntar si la ecdsa_key y la ecdsa_public tienen que estar almacenadas (por ejemplo, en el archivo credentials.yml), o son claves que se generan cada vez que un usuario intenta iniciar sesión y validarse?

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Nunca he usado jwt, pero podrías echar una mirada a [este ejemplo de implementación en rails](https://medium.com/binar-academy/rails-api-jwt-authentication-a04503ea3248).